# allowing to add Parameters in creating email template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, parameters

I want that user can create their own template for sending emails and looking a way they can add their own parameters and I can catch the parameters and add the actual value from the database.

I am using Simiditor for editing the text

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0JE3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0JE3.png)

I couldn't find a good solution yet

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to allow a user to edit a text template with the following parameters

```
{clientName}
{selectedVonderName}
```

then add the actual value from the database (say mysql data)

In that case, use str_replace to do the job

Say for example if you get the data from the mysql db data and then assign the data as `$clientName` and `$selectedVonderName`, then

```
<?php
/// other code

$text=".......{clientName} ....{selectedVonderName}";

$text=str_replace("{clientName}", $clientName, $text);
$text=str_replace("{selectedVonderName}", $selectedVonderName, $text);

/// other code
?>
```